# Finding rotated function on a sphere in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a scalar valued function $$f(\theta,\phi)$$ on a sphere. Following
[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611951/rotate-a-scalar-valued-spherical-function), I get
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
f'(\theta',\phi')\sin\theta'\cos\phi'\\
f'(\theta',\phi')\sin\theta'\sin\phi'\\
f'(\theta',\phi')\cos\theta'
\end{pmatrix}
=R.\begin{pmatrix}
f(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
f(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
f(\theta,\phi)\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $$R$$ is the rotation matrix. Is there a way to solve for $$f'(\theta',\phi')$$ using Mathematica? I tried using `Solve` but it returned the error "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve".
Any help would be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: `fp[θ_, φ_] := f @@ Rest[ToSphericalCoordinates[R . FromSphericalCoordinates[{1, θ, φ}]]]` could work if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Roman Hm, for some reason, this is giving me zero everywhere. I tried ```f[theta_, phi_]:=Exp[-theta^2]Cos[phi]``` and ```R={{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `f` be your function that you wish to rotate

```
 f[θ_,ϕ_]:=4/5+2Cos[θ]Cos[ϕ]
```

The rotations are best parametrized by the **Euler angles**

```
EulerRotSpherical[{θ_,ϕ_},{α_,β_,γ_}]:=Module[{},
  {ArcCos[Cos[θ]Cos[β]+Sin[θ]Sin[β]Cos[ϕ-α]],
   ArcTan[Cos[ϕ-α]Cos[β]-Cot[θ]Sin[β],Sin[ϕ-α]]-γ}
  ]

InverseEulerRotSpherical[{θ_,ϕ_},{α_,β_,γ_}]:=Module[{},
  {ArcCos[Cos[θ]Cos[β]-Sin[θ]Sin[β]Cos[ϕ+γ]],
   ArcTan[(Cos[ϕ+γ]Cos[β]+Cot[θ]Sin[β]),Sin[ϕ+γ]]+α}
  ]
```

Now we manipulate the plot

```
Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[f@@InverseEulerRotSpherical[{θ,ϕ},{α,β,γ}],
  {θ,0,Pi},{ϕ,0,2Pi},
  PlotRange->{{-3,3},{-3,3},{-3,3}},
  Mesh->None,
  PerformanceGoal->"Quality"],
{α,0,2π},{β,0,π},{γ,0,2π}]
```

Corresponding rotation formulas can be found in p. 23 (Eqs. 2, 3) of Varshalovich *Quantum Theory of Angular Momentum* (World Scientific Pub. 1988). The book is in [free access](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/0270) from the publisher. For convenience I retype the formulas here:

**Direct transform:**

$$\cos\theta'=\sin(\beta) \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi -\alpha)+\cos(\beta) \cos(\theta),\\
\cot(\phi'+\alpha)=\frac{\cos(\beta ) \cos(\phi -\alpha)-\sin(\beta) \cot(\theta)}{\sin(\phi -\alpha)}.
$$

**Inverse transform:**
$$\cos\theta=\cos(\beta) \cos(\theta')-\sin(\beta) \sin(\theta' ) \cos(\gamma +\phi'),\\
\cot(\phi-\alpha)=\frac{\cos(\beta ) \cos(\gamma +\phi' )+\sin(\beta) \cot(\theta')}{\sin(\gamma +\phi')}.
$$
In these equations

- $0\le\theta<\pi,0\le\phi<2\pi$ are the initial spherical coordinates (angles),
- $0\le\theta'<\pi,0\le\phi'<2\pi$ are the transformed (rotated) angles,
- $0\le\alpha<2\pi, 0\le\beta<\pi, 0\le\gamma<2\pi$ are
  the [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) ($z$-$y$-$z$).

Finally, in the case when a rotation matrix is given instead of the Euler angles, they can be found using the `EulerAngles`command.

Comment: @123infinity does my post answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But this doesn't give me f', does it? I was hoping to get f'(theta',phi') and substitute the values of theta' and phi' to find the rotated function.

Comment: @123infinity $f'(\theta',\phi')=f(\theta,\phi)=f(\theta(\theta',\phi'), \phi(\theta',\phi'))$, as exactly written in my post.

Comment: Okay,that makes sense. Thanks!